# JQuery DataTables: How to append new line in csv file

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using Jquery Datatables for csv generation. I want to append a empty line at the end csv file. How can I do this?

**Updated the code with new function and its working for me.**

```
            var dtbl = $("#").DataTable({
                dom: 'Blfrtip',
                lengthChange: true,
                lengthMenu: [[20, 100, 50, -1], [20, 50, 100, "All"]],
                colReorder: true,
                buttons: [
                     {
                         extend: 'csv',
                         footer:true,
                         filename: $("#Name").val() ? $("#Name").val() : 'Exported_File',
                         customize: function (csvz) {
                             csvz = csvz + ",\n";
                             return csvz;
                         }
                     },
                      {
                          extend: 'excel',
                          filename: $("#Name").val() ? $("#Name").val() : 'Exported_File'
                      },
                      {
                          extend: 'pdf',
                          filename: $("#Name").val() ? $("#Name").val() : 'Exported_File'
                      },
                       {
                           extend: 'print',
                           filename: $("#Name").val() ? $("#Name").val() : 'Exported_File',
                           title: $("#Name").val() ? $("#Name").val() : 'Exported_File'
                       }

                ]
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked this post of the DataTables forum ?

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/36045/excel-export-add-rows-and-data

Comment: No problem, glad that I could help you.